# Usando o navbar-collapse do bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ao usar o *navbar-collapse* do *bootstrap* em tela pequenas (celular), queria minimizar ao escolher um item do menu.

Alguém já conseguiu isso?

Comment: Consegui a resposta na propria w3scholl... http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_navigation.asp Mudei o tipo de "Navigation Bars", mas acabei voltando atrás. Não gostei do resultado.